# Use dojox.validate on Dijit ValidationTextBox, but not make text required

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

In my Dijit form, I have the following ValidationTextBox:

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
    name="email" data-dojo-props="required: true,
    validator:dojox.validate.isEmailAddress, 
    invalidMessage: 'Invalid email'" />
```

However, I would like to make the field *not* required (i.e. allow it to be empty), but still use the dojox.validate method. Removing `required: true` or explicitly setting `required: false` doesn't seem to work; the field still says "Invalid email." How can I only use the validation method if text is present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own validator  and set required=false, so something like:

```
 <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
    name="email" data-dojo-props="required: false,
    validator: function(text){
                   if (!text){
                     return true;
                   }
                   return dojox.validate.isEmailAddress(text);
                  },
    invalidMessage: 'Invalid email'" />
```